# create parent instance from main method of sub class

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I try to create parent instance in the main method of sub class. It show an error: "constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types". Please tell me why my code doesn't work. Thanks

```
class A
{
    protected int a;
    A(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

class Test extends A
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        A instance = new A(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not at line

```
A instance = new A(a);
```

The problem is that, as you haven't defined any constructor in Test, the compiler is supposed to provide one of the following form:

```
Test() {
    super();
}
```

But it can't because the superclass (A) doesn't have any default constructor. So, you need to provide a constructor explivitely:

```
Test() {
    super(0);
}
```

or

```
Test(int i) {
    super(i);
}
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your line `A instance = new A(a);`  That is not where your compile error is coming from.

In Class A you have defined a constructor `A(int a)` which prevents the *default* (no parameter) constructor from being auto-generated.

The reason you're getting the compilation error is that you're extending A with `class Test extends A` and not calling your super class' constructor.  It's looking for a *default* constructor for class A.